# Strategy for Excel Formula or VBA to do this.

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with information about auto parts.

Part number is on A2. First Vehicle it fits is on B3. Second Vehicle it fits is on B4. Third vehicle it fits is on B5. And so on and so forth until the next Part Number for the next part. Some parts have hundreds of vehicles they fit. Some have 0 (parts for non-US cars).

I need to have the part number on A3, A4, A5, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool trick to fix this - Do the following:

1. Select the entire region in column A you want to fill in
2. Prsee the `F5` key
3. Select `Special`
4. Select `Blanks` and click `Ok`

Now all the blank cells chould be chosen

1. Type in `=` and press the `up arrow`
2. Hit `ctrl` + `enter`

That should do it

Comment: Then select the column and copy / paste values so you don't have issues with sorting, removing lines etc. down the line.

Comment: Thanks man. That was an awesome solution. I was going crazy trying out far more complex solutions