# Naming multiple ranges using blank cells in column A to define the range size

Tags: vba, loops, excel, range

Firstly I'm new to this so please forgive me if I seem ignorant or if my request is poorly formatted.

I have a spreadsheet that has been exported from an ERP system. Column A contains a part number followed by a varying number of blank rows (the number of rows depends on how much data is in columns B to H).

What I need to do is name a range that starts with the first cell in column A that contains a part number and extends to the last blank cell before the cell in column A that contains the next part number. e.g. A1:H10 if A11 contains the second part number.

Then I want to loop the code so that it names the range of data from part number 2 down to the blank cell above part number 3 and so on right down the sheet (which contains about 2000 populated rows and 150-200 PNs).

I'm pretty sure I can code the rest I just can't figure out how to select the appropriate number of rows.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Pete

Comment: ... I answered what I believe to be the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884341/strategy-for-excel-formula-or-vba-to-do-this/13884438#13884438

Comment: Ill have to check this out. It looks like a slightly different issue but i may be able to adapt it to my needs. Thanks John.

Comment: I just re-read your question, are you saying you want to name the blank cell ranges between the part numbers a specific name? Can you elaborate and I'll see if I can help more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon what I understand of what you wrote, I came up with this short sub that should at least move you in the right direction:

```
Sub test()

Dim FirstCell As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim NameCounter As Integer

Set FirstCell = Range("A1")
NameCounter = 1

  Do
     Set TargetRange = Range(FirstCell, FirstCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 7))
     TargetRange.Name = "Name_" & NameCounter
     Set FirstCell = FirstCell.End(xlDown)
     NameCounter = NameCounter + 1
  Loop Until FirstCell.Row > 1000000

End Sub
```

The main part you asked for being `Set TargetRange = Range(FirstCell, FirstCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 7))`

Hope that helps

Comment: John this works perfectly. I need to tweak a few bits to get the names of the ranges right etc. but you have given me a big head start. Thank you :)